# Are fields guaranteed to be consistent after a successful join() of the CompletableFuture setting them?

Tags: java, thread-safety, future

I am using [`CompletableFuture.runAsync()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync-java.lang.Runnable-) to asynchronously initialise a few fields in an object. As the fields are used frequently long after the initialisation, I don't want to mark then as `volatile`.

Could someone give definitive reference on whether the fields will be consistent after `join()` on the `Future` has successfully returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `join()` and `get()` methods block caller thread until result will be ready (or exception will be thrown). When runner thread completes the task it notifies threads waiting for the results.

These two actions (wait-notify) make a synchronization order between execution flows and it's guaranteed that all updates made by the runner thread before notification will be seen in waiting threads when they wake up.